# How do I structure Tkinter app so it is made up of many nested frames, each containing widgets and those frames are recorded as separate classes?

Tags: class, oop, tkinter

I've been writing Tkinter apps where all the attributes, methods and widgets are contained within main class which extends from tk.Tk.
The problem is that my app started growing and becoming more complex.
I've been trying to organise the code/structure of the Tkinter class so it is made of multiple cases, for instance:
main frame class which can hold left frame class and right frame class and these can also hold other frames (also classes).
How do I organise the code to accomplish that?
Also, how do I write button action methods that can be triggered from left frame but have an affect on right frame.  Below code kind of demonstrates what I've been trying to do. Notice that two square frames should stick to west and east side of the main frame but are instead sticking to Tkinter window.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("tkinter test")
        self.geometry(f'1200x750')
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.main_frame = MainFrame()
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.left_frame = LeftFrame(self.main_frame)
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")

        self.right_frame = RightFrame(self.main_frame)
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self["height"] = 650
        self["width"] = 1100
        self["bg"] = "blue"


class LeftFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        self["height"] = 300
        self["width"] = 300
        self["bg"] = "red"

class RightFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        self["height"] = 300
        self["width"] = 300
        self["bg"] = "green"


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

I've tried to return the frame from the class but it does not work. It seems that I can only place mainframe inside of tk window but other frames are not contained within mainframe...
I've looked everywhere online but could not find examples of nested frames as classes, only individual components nested within main window.

Comment: You need to specify the parent in `super().__init__()`, otherwise the root window will be used.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I've managed to place subframes into mainframe.

Comment: Adding parent to super places frames inside the frame but when I try to add button to the frame it changes the frame, the frame wraps around that button. What am I doing wrong...?

Comment: It is normal.  If you don't want the frame be resized, call `.grid_propagate(0)` or `.pack_propagate(0)` on the frame based on how you put the button.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Last thing I struggle with is how to call a method from another class. For instance if the button is placed inside a left frame, and I want to change the color of the right frame with the button click and they are both in separate classes, it does not work well. I've managed to instantiate main app class in left frame so that I have access to it's methods but when I call it then the left frame button disappears

change = LeftFrame(master)
button = tk.Button(master=self, text="right button", command=change.change_color)
button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="we")

Comment: Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/jXe15A5Z

Comment: It is better to raise another question with a [mre].

Comment: Ok. I'll do that. Thanks